# SQL Server Need to Loop Through Select Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL statement that returns some statements from a table.

```
-- get make/normal BOMs...
select b.TopLevelItemNumber as TopLevel
, case
  when b.InEffectivityDate > getdate() or b.OutEffectivityDate < getdate() then 'Not In Effect'
  else replicate('.', b.BillLevel) + cast(b.BillLevel as varchar(9)) end Bill_Level
, b.ParentItemNumber as Parent, b.ParentItemDescription Parent_Desc, b.PointOfUseID as POU, b.OperationSequenceNumber as Seq
, b.ComponentItemNumber as Component, b.ComponentItemDescription as CompDesc
, b.ComponentItemUM as UoM, b.ComponentItemMakeBuyCode as MB, b.ComponentType as CT, b.RequiredQuantity as Reqd_Qty, b.QuantityType as QT
, b.LeadTimeOffsetDays as LTO, b.ConfigurationGroup as OptGrp, b.ConfigurationType as OptTyp
, case
  when b.ComponentType in ('R') then ''
  when b.BackflushStockroom != '' then b.BackflushStockroom + ' ~ ' + b.BackflushBin
  when i2.PreferredStockroom != '' then i2.PreferredStockroom + ' ~ ' + i2.PreferredBin
  else 'WIP' end Orig_Loc
, case
  when b.ComponentType in ('R') then ''
  when b.BackflushStockroom != '' then 'BackFlushed' when i2.PreferredStockroom != '' then 'Picked'
  else '' end Issue_Via
, case when i1.PreferredStockroom != '' then i1.PreferredStockroom + ' ~ ' + i1.PreferredBin else 'WIP' end Dest_Loc
, b.BillLevelSort
, @timestamp as timestamp
into #bom_mn
from _NoLock_FS_MultiLevelBillAll b
 left join _NoLock_FS_Item i1 on b.ParentItemKey = i1.ItemKey
 left join _NoLock_FS_Item i2 on b.ComponentItemKey = i2.ItemKey
where b.TopLevelItemNumber in (select * from #mn)
order by b.BillLevelSort

    -- combine and identify kit items...
select row_number() over(partition by b.TopLevel order by b.BillLevelSort) + .1 as row
, case when b.Parent in (select * from #mn) then 'Kit' else m.TopLevel + '~' + m.Parent + '~' + m.Component end Kit
, b.*
into #kit
from #bom b left join #bom_mn m on b.Parent = m.Parent and b.Component = m.Component
order by b.BillLevelSort

--DECLARE @Loop_Counter Int = 1, @Starting_Row Int, @Ending_Row Int
Select k.row, k.Bill_Level, k.CT, k.Component, k.CompDesc, Case When k.CT = 'N' Then 'Start of Kit' Else '' End TEST 
--While (@Loop_Counter <= @@ROWCOUNT)
--Begin
--Select kit.row = @Loop_Counter
From #kit k Where k.MB = 'M' --and k.CT = 'N' 
--SELECT COUNT(*) From #kit
Order by k.BillLevelSort
```

My question is this: every row with the TEST column marked with 'Start of Kit' I need to mark every row after with 'Part of Kit' in the TEST column until I get to the next .1 in the Bill_Level column. Can someone help me make a loop that I can add to my original SQL statement listed above?

[image]

Comment: 1) avoid screenshots 2) provide desired ouput as well

Comment: Please provide full [mre]

Comment: Never loop in SQL

Comment: Just curious...why do all your object names begin with "_NoLock"?

Comment: I've updated my example above. Some of the code above was created by a different user, not sure why he used _NoLock

Answer (score 0):

What other possible values can be in column TEST?
If only 'Start of Kit' and 'Part of Kit' just modify Your CASE statement...

```
Select k.row, k.Bill_Level, k.CT, k.Component, k.CompDesc, 
Case When k.CT = 'N' Then 'Start of Kit' Else 'Part of Kit' End TEST 
--While (@Loop_Counter <= @@ROWCOUNT)
--Begin
--Select kit.row = @Loop_Counter
From #kit k Where k.MB = 'M' --and k.CT = 'N' 
--SELECT COUNT(*) From #kit
Order by k.BillLevelSort
```